# redis execError in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, apiaxle

In my node application i am using redis server for my data store. In that frequently i am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors.
```

I am new to redis and node.js.I searched a lot in google for this error, but i cant find the correct solution.

Somebody suggesting for `FLUSHALL` command , i tried that also, but still i am getting the same error.

Some suggestions is that the problem is regarding `MAXMEMORY`, i am not clear about it.
Help me to solve this.Thanks in advance

My configuration file:

```
{
  "redis": {
    "host": "localhost",    
    "port": 6379    
  },
  "logging": {
  "level": "INFO",
  "appenders": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "filename": "/home/testuser/production.log"
    },
    {
      "type": "console"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

One more thing i am using apiaxle(third party product), in that only i am getting this error

Comment: That error is not coming from Redis. Which libraries are you using to connect to the database?

Comment: Thanks @soveran .. redis library..Anyway i updated my question with my configuration file..